# Why would a Web2Py website work locally but give me errors when I upload it to PythonAnywhere? How would I fix an error I don't get locally?

Tags: web2py, pythonanywhere

I created an app successfully from a Tutorial on Web2Py but when I uploaded the application to PythonAnywhere, I received this error:

Error ticket for "pluralsight"
Ticket ID

75.159.30.26.2020-07-17.15-41-34.00821419-8e86-4d99-881d-c2cb400d0e22
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'> unsupported pickle protocol: 3
Version
web2py™     Version 2.18.5-stable+timestamp.2019.04.08.04.22.03
Python  Python 2.7.12: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi (prefix: /usr)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running web2py on Python 3 locally and with Python 2 on PythonAnywhere.  The best solution would be to upgrade it on PythonAnywhere:

- Make sure that you're using the most recent version of web2py itself by upgrading it from the main admin page inside your hosted web2py.
- Once it's fully upgraded, go to the "Web" page inside PythonAnywhere and change the Python version to the version of Python 3 that matches the one that you're using locally (eg. 3.7 or 3.8)
- Reload the site using the green button at the top of the "Web" page inside PythonAnywhere.

Then you should be able to upload your app.